# Angular $scope won't update in bootbox callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, bootbox, ng-boot-box

This is my first question on SO.

When I splice an element of an array on the scope, that change is not reflected, when done in a callback of bootbox.js.

Works:

```
$scope.deleteA = function() {
    if (confirm("Really delete Item 3?")) {
      $scope.itemsA.splice(2, 1);
    }
}
```

Does not work:

```
$scope.deleteB = function() {
    bootbox.confirm("Really delete Item 3?", function(answer) {
      if (answer === true) {
        $scope.itemsB.splice(2, 1);
      }
    });
}
```

I'm mainly interested in understanding the **why**. This is much more important to me than having a fancy workaround.

[I created a Plunker to show the effect](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZDETsFJeKJKjSa4to4vb?p=preview)

Comment: in bootbox callback angular not know that something changes, that's why not update view

Comment: Consider using [ng-boot-box](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ng-boot-box/info), an AngularJS wrapper for Bootbox.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any change happens with angular scope variable from ouside world of angular, doesn't intimate angular digest system to run digest cycle for updating binding.
 In `bootbox` callback angular not know that something change, that's why not update view.
For solving this issue, you need to kick off digest cycle manually by using  [`$apply` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply), or [`$timeout` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), like this

```
bootbox.confirm("Really delete Item 3?", function(answer) {
  if (answer === true) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.itemsB.splice(2, 1);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello @Grundy. Thank you for your answer. I see, that this solution works, but I still don't understand WHY angular 'sees' the changes made, when they are done in a scope-function, but doesn't see them, when they are done in a function, which is also defined inside a scope-function. Where does the world of Angular stop and why?

Comment: @DannySoul, because on every users event, like `click`, `change`, `keyup` and etc angular run digest loop automatically, and update view if needed, in your case - angular not run this after bootbox callback, and you should run it manually

Comment: @Grundy, thanks for your answer again. But I still don't really understand it. Let's assume `$scope.name` is a String with a name in it. It is known to angular. If I change the value of `$scope.name` from within a function `$scope.myFunction` it is reflected in the view. If I change the value from within a function that I define inside of `$scope.myFunction` (`setTimeout` for example) it is not reflected. Why is angular able to see it in one case but not in the other. Why does the **calling** function matter?

Comment: @DannySoul, try read a bit more about [HTML Compiler](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) and [angular scope life cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle)

Answer (score 0):

Safe method to apply scope change would be using `$timeout` service.

```
bootbox.confirm("Really delete Item 3?", function(answer) {
  if (answer === true) {
    $timeout($scope.itemsB.splice(2, 1));
  }
});
```

So you dont need to worry about `$digest` phase and your `$apply` will be one high call stack take a look at [AngularJS Wiki - Anti-Patterns](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Dev-Guide%3A-Anti-Patterns)  point -2 .

> Don't do `if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()`, it means your
>   `$scope.$apply()` isn't high enough in the call stack.

Comment: The use of `$timeout` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem.  Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is needed only when implementing custom event callbacks, or when working with third-party library callbacks.